# Workflow Question using lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I want to add a Workflow to a list. The list contains a lookup field that references a master client list. I want the Workflow to send an email every time a item is added to the list. I know how to do this part. I want to include information from the "Client" List in the email. How do I create the workflow expression to pull the required fields from "Client" into the email based on the value of the lookup field in the list?

```
List1 = Client
List2 = Billing
List2 includes a lookup field to List1
```

List1 has fields called Address, City, State, Zip that I want to include in the email.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a few variables and use a workflow lookup to set their values. Click the Fx button to open the lookup dialog

[image]

- In the Data Source drop-down, select the client list.
- use the next drop-down to select the desired field
- in the section "Find List Item" select the field by which you want to identify the client, e.g. "ClientCode"
- in the value box use the client field from the current item, e.g. "ClientCode"

You may get a warning that the lookup can return more than one item, but if the client codes are unique, you can just click OK.

You can then plug the variables into the email body. (You could do the lookup right in the email body, but I find it more manageable to use variables).